# using namespace std

Tags: c++, namespaces

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Why is 'using namespace std;' considered a bad practice in C++?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1452721/why-is-using-namespace-std-considered-a-bad-practice-in-c)

I have done a little research and am looking for something close to the definitive answer on whether or not, as a farily new programmer (and very new to C++) I should get in the habit of including "using namespace std;" after my included libraries.  OR do you guys recommend I start with identifying the scope everytime and use namespaces later?  Namespaces now, namespaces later...  The professor leaves it up to us and as our programs are fairly simple right now I don't know if it's too critical either way.  I'd love to hear opinions.  Thanks!

Comment: whatever you feel more comfortable with

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1452721/why-is-using-namespace-std-considered-a-bad-practice-in-c

Comment: The important thing is, don't put `using` *in* your header files (at least, not in the global namespace) - that imposes it on users of the header, possibly breaking their code. Within a source file, it's more a matter of personal taste.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Get in the habit of **not** `using namespace std`. It'll make your life easier when you start using lots of libraries with each their own namespace and potentially conflicting identifiers.

If you want to abbreviate, say, `std::cout` to `cout`, you can always declare

```
using std::cout;
```